# Reverse word by word in a String

Tags: java, string

I am trying to reverse the words in a string word by word. But I am running into a bit of trouble. I know many people have used `StringBuilder` to do this problem but I wanted to try it out without it.

Input:

```
Hi there
```

Output:

```
iH ereht
```

Currently, my input string stops at the last word. I assume this is due to the fact that in my code, the reverse portion of the code only reverses when a `' '` or space is detected. I changed this by performing the reverse portion when the end of the string has been reached as well. (`i == len`) However this does not seem to fix the problem. I assume there is some logic error inside my `if`, `else if` statements and `for loop` as well. I was wondering if anyone could guide me in the right direction.

The test case string that I've been working on is

`"Hi there Mr.Doge!"`

The output I get right now is

`iH ereht`  <-- space at the end of the string.

I printed some text as the code proceeds and the last word (`Mr.Doge!`) is being stored into `temp` but it is not being reverse.

Here is the output when I compile the code:

```
0
H
1
Hi
2
i
iH
3
t
4
th
5
the
6
ther
7
there
8
iH e
iH er
iH ere
iH ereh
iH ereht
9
M
10
Mr
11
Mr.
12
Mr.D
13
Mr.Do
14
Mr.Dog
15
Mr.Doge
16
Mr.Doge!
iH ereht
```

My code:

```
public static String reverseWord(String str){
    int len = str.length();
    String reverse = "", temp = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        if (str.charAt(i) != ' '){
            temp += str.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
        else if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' || i == len){
        //if (str.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            for (int j = temp.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {      // reverse
                reverse += temp.charAt(j);                      // append in reverse
                System.out.println(reverse);
            }
            reverse += ' ';
            temp = "";
        }
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `StringBuilder`? If you use a string, You'll be creating a new string every time you append to it and reduce efficiency. Well at least in C#, but I'm sure the same applies to Java.

Comment: In the code above, the `for` loop has condition `i< len`, so your `else if` needs to match `str.charAt(i) == ' ' || i == (len-1)`

Comment: I'm not a fan of all the charats and numbers. Maybe [this approach](https://ideone.com/D2ZU3W) might be helpful to you.

Comment: @Manish i tried this and it didnt do what I wanted to =/

Comment: Since you are interested in reversing the words in the string, you should focus on the word count and not on the string size. iterating and backtracking would be easier with this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a couple of modifications this must work. See comments in code, to see what I modified.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(reverseWord("Hello world Liondancer"));
}

public static String reverseWord(String str)
{
    int len = str.length();
    String reverse = "", temp = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {   // i == len comparison is unuseful since 'i' won't never be 'len'
        if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            temp = str.charAt(i) + temp; // What you did, but add the current character first, THIS IS THE REVERSE!!!
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            reverse += temp + " ";
            temp = "";
        }
    }
    reverse += temp; // Added this outside the loop to add last word stored in 'temp'
    return reverse;
}
```

**Output:**

```
olleH dlrow recnadnoiL
```

**Note:**

I deleted the nested `for` since it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

try this change

```
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (c != ' '){
            temp = c + temp;
        } else {
            reverse += temp + ' ';
            temp = "";
        }
    }
    reverse += temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse outside your loop and check that you're not at the last word (like so) -

```
public static String reverseWord(String str) {
  int len = str.length();
  String reverse = "", temp = " ";

  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {
      temp += str.charAt(i);
    } else if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' || i == len) {
      if (i + 1 < len) {
        for (int j = temp.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) { // reverse
          reverse += temp.charAt(j); // append in reverse
        }
        temp = " ";
      } else {
        temp = "";
      }
    }
  }
  for (int j = temp.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) { // reverse
    reverse += temp.charAt(j); // append in reverse
  }
  return reverse;
}
```

Comment: that only reverses the first word in the string

Answer (score 0):

If i were to do it I would just store entire string in an arraylist.
then say:

```
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    temp.size()=len;
    temp(length-i)=str(i);
    print temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the loop in this way too...

```
   public String reverseString(String str){
       String reverse="";

       for(int i=str.length()-1; i>=0; i--){

           reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);

       }
          return reverse;

   }
```